# sqlite3 foreign keys ignored

Tags: foreign-key, sqlite, constraint

I am working on a small sqlite3 database for a small simple mailserver. I have created a new sqlite3 database and add executed this to pürepare it for data:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE `mailboxes` (
    `username`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `domain`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    `mailbox`   TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(`domain`) REFERENCES domains(domain)
    UNIQUE (username, domain),
    UNIQUE (mailbox)
);
CREATE TABLE `domains` (
    `domain`    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE `aliases` (
    `aliasname` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `domain`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    `destination`   TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(`domain`) REFERENCES domains(domain)
    UNIQUE (aliasname, domain)
);
COMMIT;
```

Foreign keys are enabled with PRAGMA and no errors are shown. As you can see, mailboxes and aliases are nearly the same. I have a list of available domains. Every mailbox/alias entry must use a valid entry of "domains". In addition to this, a "username - domain" pair should only appear once. BUT: the same mail can appear in mailboxes and aliases.

#### PROBLEM

I have no entries in my domains table, but executing this works (but it should not, because it is not a valid domain):

```
INSERT INTO aliases (aliasname, domain, destination)
VALUES ('test', 'myacc.de', 'other@worldwide.com');
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: Works for me (`Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed`).

Answer (score 2):

I was partially able to reproduce your bug when having `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`, but setting the `domain` column in the `domains` table as `PRIMARY KEY` removed any problem in my case. (Still keep the pragma on).