# Foreign keys not working

Tags: foreign-key, sqlite, constraint

I have created a db, and my problem is that I can insert **ANY** value in FK.

Sorry for having the values in Spanish.

This is my Database:

```
CREATE TABLE "Articulo" (
`ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`nombre`    TEXT NOT NULL,
`precio`    REAL NOT NULL,
`cantidad`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
`nombre_usuario`    TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(`nombre_usuario`) REFERENCES Usuario)

CREATE TABLE `Categoria` (
    `nombre`    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(nombre)
)

CREATE TABLE "Categoria_Articulo" (
    `ID_articulo`   INTEGER,
    `nombre`    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_articulo,nombre),
    FOREIGN KEY(`ID_articulo`) REFERENCES Articulo,
    FOREIGN KEY(`nombre`) REFERENCES Categoria
)

CREATE TABLE "Pedido" (
        `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        `precio_total`  REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        `nombre_usuario`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        `fecha` TEXT NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY(`nombre_usuario`) REFERENCES Usuario
    )

CREATE TABLE "Linea_Pedido" (
    `ID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `precio_total`  REAL NOT NULL,
    `cantidad`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `ID_pedido` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(`ID_pedido`) REFERENCES Pedido
)

CREATE TABLE "Linea_Pedido_Articulo" (
    `ID_linea_pedido`   INTEGER,
    `ID_articulo`   INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_linea_pedido,ID_articulo),
    FOREIGN KEY(`ID_linea_pedido`) REFERENCES Linea_Pedido,
    FOREIGN KEY(`ID_articulo`) REFERENCES Articulo
)

CREATE TABLE "Linea_Pedido_Articulo" (
    `ID_linea_pedido`   INTEGER,
    `ID_articulo`   INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID_linea_pedido,ID_articulo),
    FOREIGN KEY(`ID_linea_pedido`) REFERENCES Linea_Pedido,
    FOREIGN KEY(`ID_articulo`) REFERENCES Articulo
)

CREATE TABLE `Usuario` (
    `nombre_usuario`    TEXT,
    `nombre`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    `apellidos` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `contraseña`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(nombre_usuario)
)

CREATE TABLE `favorito` (
    `usuario_tiene_favorito`    TEXT,
    `usuario_es_favorito`   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(usuario_tiene_favorito,usuario_es_favorito),
    FOREIGN KEY(`usuario_tiene_favorito`) REFERENCES Usuario,
    FOREIGN KEY(`usuario_es_favorito`) REFERENCES Usuario
)
```

For example, I am able to insert in `Linea_Pedido_Articulo` in my all empty database which is an `N-N` relationship, the values I wanted, when it should show an error.

I have found [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120887/sqlite3-foreign-keys-ignored) similar question, but it is not well answered I think.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: See this: https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html (especially section **2. Enabling Foreign Key Support**).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  I have execute that before, but I think not in the right place, where have I to put the **PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;**?. Thanks!

Comment: You can use dbfiddle.uk when posting questions. Very helpful, for you and others to answer: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=7b7705d04fefa4771d68207a1add30f2

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the FK constraint, because they are not enabled. I am using DB Browser for SQLite, so you only have to go here in order to enable it:
[image]

Then just check that Foreign Keys is enabled:
[image]